# Hibernate Stored procedure Invalid Column Name Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, sybase, jconnect

I'm trying to solve an error of "Invalid Column Name Exception" after calling Stored Procedure from java with hibernate.
My Procedure select data from two tables, ari_immatricule , art_article. both of them has a column called code_art. but the procedure returns instead a param called @P_CODE_ARTI.
Here is my Entity

```
public class ArticleEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer code;
    private String libelle;
}
```

NamedProcedure

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "@P_CODE_ARTI", type = Integer.class)
```

Mapping.

```
@FieldResult(name = "code", column = "@P_CODE_ARTI")
```

Stored procedure :

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE S0_CONT_APT_codebarre
( @P_CODE_IMMA char(20),
  @P_CODE_ARTI int output,
  @P_TAILLE_ATA char(4) output,
  @P_POIDS_ATA numeric(6,0) output,
  @P_CODE_FAM char(6) output,
  @P_TIME_STAMP_ARI timestamp output,
  @P_CODE_PTL_CAR char(6) output,
  @P_CODE_PTL int output,
  @P_CODE_SRV int output,
  @P_CODE_EXP int output,
  @P_INDIC_SERVI_STT bit output,
  @P_NB_LAV_MAX smallint output,
  @P_NB_LAV_ARI smallint output,
  @P_CODE_TOU tinyint output
)
AS
DECLARE
  @ERR_VALUE int,
  @NB_ROWS int
DECLARE @P_IND_ARI_SUP bit,
          @P_CODE_ATP numeric(10,0)
SELECT
 @P_CODE_ARTI = ari.code_arti,
 @P_TAILLE_ATA = ari.taille_ata,
 @P_POIDS_ATA = art.poids_moy_article,
 @P_TIME_STAMP_ARI = ari.time_stamp,
 @P_CODE_FAM = art.code_fam,
 @P_IND_ARI_SUP = ari.ind_ari_sup,
 @P_CODE_ATP = ari.code_atp,
        @P_NB_LAV_MAX = art.nb_lav_max,
        @P_NB_LAV_ARI = ari.nbre_lav_ari
FROM
        ari_arti_immatricule ari,
 art_article art
WHERE
 ari.code_imma = @P_CODE_IMMA
  AND art.code_arti = ari.code_arti
```

As a Result i get the value of @_CODE_ARTI but i still have the error in the log file, I'm using Sybase for Database.

```
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.SQL:92 - {call S0_CONT_APT_codebarre(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.r.i.OutputsImpl:178 - Building Return [isResultSet=true, updateCount=-1, extendedReturn=false
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.l.Loader:384 - Result set row: 0
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:122 - Error extracting results from CallableStatement [S0_CONT_APT_codebarre]
java.sql.SQLException: S0022: '@P_CODE_ARTI' est un nom de colonne incorrect.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsResultSet.findColumnByLabel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet.findColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CustomLoaderExtension.processResultSet(OutputsImpl.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractResults(OutputsImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractCurrentResults(OutputsImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.access$100(OutputsImpl.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.buildOutput(OutputsImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.getOutput(OutputsImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.getCurrent(OutputsImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
    at com.app.common.persitance.jpa.repository.AppProcedureTask.runProcedure(AppProcedureTask.java:55)
    at com.app.common.persitance.jpa.repository.RepositoryInvocationHandler.invoke(RepositoryInvocationHandler.java:39)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.getArticleByCodeImmaS0(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService.callArticleRepositoryByCodeImma(ArticleService.java:414)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService.getArticleByCodeImma(ArticleService.java:399)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2136c0c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e8f1228.getArticleByCodeImma(<generated>)
    at com.app.ace.api.resource.ArticleRessource.getArticle(ArticleRessource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | WARN  | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | ERROR | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:129 - S0022: '@P_CODE_ARTI' est un nom de colonne incorrect.
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.j.s.AbstractEntityManagerImpl:1494 - Mark transaction for rollback
2018-11-09 17:01:48 | DEBUG | [http-nio-8080-exec-9] c.e.c.p.j.r.AppProcedureTask:60 - Erreur à la première execution
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error extracting results from CallableStatement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:224)
    at com.app.common.persitance.jpa.repository.AppProcedureTask.runProcedure(AppProcedureTask.java:55)
    at com.app.common.persitance.jpa.repository.RepositoryInvocationHandler.invoke(RepositoryInvocationHandler.java:39)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.getArticleByCodeImmaS0(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService.callArticleRepositoryByCodeImma(ArticleService.java:414)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService.getArticleByCodeImma(ArticleService.java:399)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2136c0c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.app.ace.core.service.ArticleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e8f1228.getArticleByCodeImma(<generated>)
    at com.app.ace.api.resource.ArticleRessource.getArticle(ArticleRessource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error extracting results from CallableStatement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractResults(OutputsImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractCurrentResults(OutputsImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.access$100(OutputsImpl.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.buildOutput(OutputsImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.getOutput(OutputsImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.getCurrent(OutputsImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: S0022: '@P_CODE_ARTI' est un nom de colonne incorrect.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsResultSet.findColumnByLabel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet.findColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CustomLoaderExtension.processResultSet(OutputsImpl.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractResults(OutputsImpl.java:136)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: That is a parameter, not a procedure

Comment: yes a parameter of a storedProcedure

Comment: there is no errror in the description(most important), no stored procedure or how you call it. People who don't know about this and might want to investigate will be stuck and cannot help you. The best would be working example on github

Comment: thanks for reply Sarief, I've just edited the question and added the log file error

Comment: look into log: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: S0022: '@P_CODE_ARTI' est un nom de colonne incorrect. <- this means it's not found in the database. try checking if it's in the database, if it's named correctly, if it's in the table you're looking for. edit: oh, right, you noticed that :D my bad

Comment: so, my suggestion is to create a small running example and check if it's still same. My best guess is that parameter is named incorrectly OR @ is preventing framework from reading it correctly. Alternatively your pointer to stored query is not completely correct

Comment: Ok, don't forget that i can get the value of @P_CODE_ARTI with no problem. there something to know that the stored procedure select data from two tables and both of theme has a column code_arti. i will put the code of the procedure too.